# how to connect to a device using JSON-RPC

Tags: json-rpc

A device I use has recently updated its external control method from simple telnet commands to json-rpc.

I am having a tough time to understand how to connect to the device and communicate with it using this method - eg ask a question and receive a response.

I have been searching for a while now and cannot find any information that I can use. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

https://q-syshelp.qsc.com/Content/External_Control/Q-Sys_Remote_Control/QRC.htm

Comment: What port are you trying to connect to?  It mentions in the documentation that it uses Port 1710 (as opposed to port 22 for Telnet)

Comment: i dont even know how to connect using json-rpc - i am now starting to understand i need a http-poster?

normally when i issue telnet commands i use port 1702 - but this protocol seems different and while i can connect with putty to port 1710 nothing i enter gives me any response

Comment: They mention the Q-SYS Communications Library - which is used by their developers, and manages the direct network connections, etc, from a library you can program with.

Comment: I have the library - it's just that this method of communicating with a piece of hardware is new to me.